# Get last modified date of XLSX files from Sharepoint and save to a Blob

Tags: excel, sharepoint, azure-data-factory, power-automate, blobstore

I'm trying to get the last modified date of XLSX files from a directory in Sharepoint and save them as an XLSX or CSV with two columns: filename and last_modified_date. After that, I want to open the saved file with Databricks. A copy of the files was made to a container using Data Factory, but the last modified date came from the copy (current copied time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi If I understood this correctly you only want the name and mofied date properties and not the file content. If this is correct you can use the "Get files (properties only)" action for this.

It will be something similar to this.

Get al the files in the directory

[image: Get files]

Then for each file get it's properties "Name" and "Modified" (This is just to show you the properties, you'll have to map each column to your new file)

[image]

You can also use the property "File name with extension" if you need it

[image: file name with extension]

Please let me know if this helps.